# Is it possible to rename only a specific level of xml tags. s

Tags: xml, xslt, rename

I have many levels of the same element name but I want to rename only the second level. Is that possible? It looks like that:

```xml
<Modifications>
  <Modifications>
     <Modifications>
     </Modifications>
  </Modifications>
</Modifications>
```

I would like to rename the second `Modifications` and the one before the last with the name `Modifications_1`.

I tried something like this:

```xml
<xsl:template match="//Modifications/Modifications">

  <xsl:element name="Modification_1">

    <xsl:apply-templates/>

  </xsl:element>

</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you can just update your match to `match="/Modifications/Modifications"` to rename the second level.

Not sure what the one before the last means and if that's a different requirement.

Also, unless you need to generate an element name it's cleaner to just output the element rather than using `xsl:element`.

```xml
<xsl:template match="/Modifications/Modifications">
  <Modification_1>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </Modification_1>
</xsl:template>
```